# Saving integers within pickle and calling them

Tags: python

So this is my code, I would like to save the value 'test' to the file so that it can be called to be used when the program is reopened.

```
import pickle
test = 0

def Save():
     with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:
         pickle.dump(test, f)

def Load():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        test = pickle.load(f)
```

*The problem with this code is that when I reopen the program and run in and then type in Load(), it says that 'test' is still equal to 0. (Missing somehting obvious probably)*

And so my question is, how could I fix the problem issued in italics?

Comment: You are saving a `0` so in fact you would get a `0` when load it

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I changed the 'test' in IDLE to differant values and it always returned 0 after reopening

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global variable `test` has nothing to do with  `test` inside the function `Load()`. Change your function to:

```
def Load():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

Now this function returns the value it reads from the pickle file.

Call it like this:

```
print(Load())
```

**Side note:** By convention functions names are all lowercase in Python. So the function name should be actually `load()`.

### EDIT

The whole program in a better style:

```
import pickle

def save(file_name, obj):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as fobj:
        pickle.dump(obj, fobj)

def load(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fobj:
        return pickle.load(fobj)

def main():
    test = 0
    file_name = 'objs.pickle'
    save(file_name, test)
    print(load(file_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the original `Load`, but add `global test` to the top of it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No `global` please. Work with return values.

Comment: @MikeMüller: If `Save` is working with globals, `Load` should as well for symmetry. Not endorsing that design in general, but fixing one and not the other is silly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger How about changing `Save()` to `save(test)`? Sounds much better to me.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Added a nicer version of the whole program.